# Intellij Idea 2022 development environment now forces me to specify the full path to some annotations

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, java-17

I have an  **Intellij-Idea 2022**  development environment, an **Ubuntu-20.x** operating system. When I set up my system and created a project with the **latest version** of **Spring boot** + **Java 17**. I noticed that the development environment now forces me to specify the **full path** to some annotations. **Previously**, it ***automatically imported*** packages.

**@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration**

```java
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class Configuration {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder() {
        return new RestTemplateBuilder();
    }
}
```

I find this inconvenient, because my opinion, meta-information of annotations or specifying fullpath packages to classes should not be in the code (this should be where all imports are specified), makes it difficult to read and analyze the code.

Maybe there is some magic setting in the development environment that was accidentally enabled?

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

Comment: If you rename your class to basically anything other than Configuration you will be able to use a non-fully-qualified reference for the annotation.

Comment: Thaks. I performed -> public class ConfigurationRestTemplate. It helped to decide the problem me.